# REVTeX 4 author issue

Tags: titles, revtex

I am trying to use the REVTeX 4 package for the first time, my code is

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\title{Title}
\author{Myname}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}

This is my abstract

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

This is my document

\end{document}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to compile it into the pdf file, it tells me:

```
! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \collaboration@sw{\expandafter \appdef \expandafter \AU@grp \exp... \author{Myname}
```

And whenever I try to compile it without an author's name, no title appears, like if `\maketitle` didn't work.

Does anybody know what's wrong? I've been trying to fix it but I'm pretty new to LaTeX...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `revtex4`, the metadata for the document (`\title`, `\author` and similar commands) should go *after* `\begin{document}`.

There's no error with

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Myname}

\begin{abstract}

This is my abstract

\end{abstract}
\maketitle

This is my document

\end{document}
```

You should consider using `revtex4-1` rather than `revtex4` (the former is the most recent revision of the class).

Comment: Thank you!! It works!! The document looks great, thanks a lot really, you saved me